# Swagger не воспринимает JsonPropertyName атрибут введённый в .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-core-3.0-webapi

У нас есть Web API проект на .Net Core 2.2. Настроен Swagger и есть следующая модель

```
public class ProjectCreateDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("project_id")]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("goods_ids")]
    public long[] GoodsIds { get; set; }
}
```

Недавно мы перешли на .Net Core 3.0 и сейчас используем System.Text.Json.Serialization. Похоже, что Swagger не поддерживает нововведённый JsonPropertyName.

Это большая проблема для всех пользователей нашего API. И так вместо ***project_id*** мы получаем ***projectId***.
Есть какой-нибудь обходной путь, чтобы совместить Swagger и новую сериализацию?

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994507/swagger-does-not-recognize-jsonpropertyname-introduced-by-net-core-3-0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570189/is-there-a-built-in-way-of-using-snake-case-as-the-naming-policy-for-json-in-asp